# How to translate "coming along?"

Tags: vocabulary, word-requests

I was recently writing a letter to a Chinese colleague and wanted to wish her luck on a book she is writing. In essence, I wanted to say

> I hope your book is coming along well.

Unfortunately, I wasn't sure how to translate this. Perhaps one might say

> 我希望你的书进展得很好。

but this doesn't have the same meaning.

How might one translate this sentence?

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't have the same meaning?

Comment: see iciba：进展得顺利

Comment: consider using 祝?  the sentence is a **wish** written on a letter.

Comment: 希望您的新书进展顺利。 希望您的新书写得顺利。

Answer (score 1):

希望你的书能顺利出版。 
希望能早日在书店等候你签名售书。。

Answer (score 1):

我祝愿您的书能顺利完成。
It literally means "I wish your book will be completed as planned". I hope this translation matches your meaning well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe you can say:
祝愿您妙笔生花，书香流芳。

Answer (score 0):

I hope your book is coming along well.
more spoken: 希望你的书写得很顺利。
Official： 希望你的书创作得很顺利。

You can also use these  sentences:
希望你的大作早日完稿。 Hope that your master piece can be finished soon.
希望早日读到你的大作。 Hope to read your book soon.